# EOF in Cat and less

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm new in Linux script and i face some commands and I didn't understand them.

```
cat <<- _EOF_
command1
command2
command3
_EOF_
```

Also,

```
less <<- _EOF
command1
command2
command3
_EOF
```

So, can any one explain them to me ?

Comment: That EOF thingy has nothing to do with either cat or less commands, but with the way here-document structure works in shell. See the link muru posted.

Comment: the cat? what do you mean?

Answer (score 6):

In program code, you have to mark which parts are meant to be commands and which are meant to be data. On typical type of data are *strings*, meaning sequences of characters (letters, digits etc.)

There are different ways to indicate string literals. The most common way is to *quote* the string data :

```
PATH="/home/user"
USER='joe'
```

But it can be hard to handle string literals that are longer and/or include line breaks:

```
MESSAGE="This is a relatively long string which isn't represented very well as a typical quoted string.\nAnd there are linebreaks in it."
```

For such cases, you would probably like to be able to say: "Treat the following as a string, until I tell you otherwise". And that's exactly what a *here document* does. It's a different way to signify a string literal. You define a marker that signifies the end of your text, then put your text, then the marker:

```
MESSAGE=<< EOF
Here be a long string.
With line breaks.
EOF
```

You're free to choose the marker, but it's typically something like *EOF* ("end of file"), *eot* ("end of text") or similar. You could have chosen "ABC" just the same

```
MESSAGE=<< ABC
Here be a long string.
With line breaks.
ABC
```

"Here documents", also known as "heredocs", "here-strings" or similar, have originated in Unix shells like `bash` and can today be found in a lot of programming languages.

In shells, they work a bit differently, as they not represent strings as much as they represent *files*. So, for example

```
cat << EOF
One
EOF
```

is equivalent to

```
cat data.txt # where data.txt contains 'One'
```

The variant with `<<-` instead of `<<' ignores leading whitespace in the heredoc data, so you can make your code more readable by identing the heredoc:

```
cat <<- EOF
  One
  Two
  Three
EOF
```

Comment: A very good explanation of the subject question.